# Is CRuntimmeClass the equivalent concept to malloc or new method in C++

Tags: mfc, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am confused with the concept of `dynamic memory allocation`, so here is what I understand:
1 In CPP we have malloc or new, to be able to use memory on heap and we can "dynamically" change the size of the memory as we the program runs.
2 In MFC there is a CRuntimeClass  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cruntimeclass-structure?view=msvc-160#createobject), after using `IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC` ,which I am not very familiar and I guess this is something similar to the the new/malloc functions

Answer (score 2):

`CRuntimeClass` is MFC's way to encode metadata for types to allow it to create objects when the type is available as a string only. This is required when constructing document instances from a `CDocTemplate`, associating views with documents, or when serializing and deserializing structured data.

To make this happen, MFC maintains an application-global in-memory registry where respective types are registered. This registry can be queried for `CRuntimeClass` implementations given a type name.

`CreateObject` isn't the equivalent of `new`. It uses `new` to construct an instance of a type available as a string representation. It can be thought of as a factory method.